# How I can make people collage in custom shape?

Tags: vector, shapes, 3d, patterns

How can I make a similar-looking collage automatically with a vector output?
I am open to any software, web application or plug-in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what do you want to use to create it? Anything? Any software goes? There are many different ways of creating these images with different software (none entirely automatic) and this makes your question really broad to answer here.

Comment: Illustrator, or any vector programme or app, just I want vector result,
I mean by automatically not put one by one (script, plugin, app,...), if you know a way semi-automatic or a few steps to make show me the most important for me is to get same result in few steps

Comment: Love Daniello’s answer - wonderful approach. Quick note: the first of OP’s example images sure *looks* like it was done in a 3D app to me... the second more Ortho / Iso one looks exactly like Daniello’s results - kudos again!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The closest in **Illustrator** made with several **Pattern Brush**

- Make many pattern brushes with three figures as shown in the gif
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag to the brush panel different figures to replace the brush end and start

[image: people]

- Make short horizontal segments inside the main shape where the figures will be, or make just one segment and after testing it with the brush, duplicate it several times. Short because each segment will have three figures.
- The segments must be in order, the lower down ahead and the rest successively back.

[image: heart]

- Select all the segments and apply a brush pattern
- Select segments randomly and change the brush pattern

[image: peopleheart]

Result 100% vector. By the way, where's Waldo?

[image: end]

Comment: Great Danielillo, thank you so much easy methode and heful, big like

Comment: +1 for a well explained answer and Waldo ;)

Comment: This question has been popping up on this site every three months the last five years. This is the best approach I've seen yet. Now I wish I could find all those old Qs to dupe them with this one.

Comment: Lol, didn't know that, it's one of the advantages of being "the new one".

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to make it automatically on Illustrator. The closest option is to paint with the **Symbol Sprayer Tool**, but it is always the same object and you can not create the sensation of depth unless you are painting in layers and with different symbols.

**Corel Painter** has a brush type called **Image Hose** with which you can paint randomly based on a group of images from a **Nozzle Library**. It is not very easy and immediate, but as everything takes time to understand and get the possibility to create something as specific as the images of your question.

There were rumors about its implementation in Photoshop as a new **Stamp Tool**' feature, but until today there is nothing.

Here a video demo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSBokJz2ZZk

The **Corel** how to use the **Image Hose** brush explanation (3 pages):

http://product.corel.com/help/Painter/540235477/707000/EN/Doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Win&file=Controlling_the_Image_Hose.html

A tutorial on this link:

http://www.gardenhose.com/PaintTrees_P.htm

The resulting image from **Painter** will not be vectorial, it's a bitmap based application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort it's helpful to create bitmap result, unfortunately this is not what I want.

Thank you again @Danielillo